# Check if there is any repeated element in a dataframe (excluding empty cells)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Hi I am trying to get "True" as output if there is a repeated element in a dataframe, and "False" if there is no repeated element. This should not take the empty cells into account.

**Example 1:**

```
import pandas as pd
data_df = {'col1': ['A','B', 'C', 'D'],

           'col2': ['E','F', '', 'G'],

           'col3': ['H', '', '  ', '  ']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_df)
```

[image]

Should display "False"

**Example 2:**

[image]

Should display "True"

**Example3:**

[image]

Should display "True"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = (df.stack()  # stack to Series, removing NaNs
         # remove empty/space strings
         .loc[lambda s: s.str.strip().ne('')]
         # is there any duplicate?
         .duplicated().any()
      )
```

Outputs:

```
False
True
True
```